# AMD/Nvidia hybrid graphics not working whatever I am trying

Tags: nvidia, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, amd-ryzen

I recently bought an Asus TUF Gaming FX505DT laptop to use for work and light gaming from time to time. But whatveer I try, I can't get Ubuntu to use the nvidia dedicated gpu, it will only use the integrated Vega 8 graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install Nvidia drivers.
Open the Software & Updates app, go to the Additional Drivers tab, and select an NVIDIA driver 440 is the latest at the moment.
Once that is done reboot and nvidia card should be working.

Comment: My problem is not the Nvidia card not working, it's the hybrid graphics not working, it will not switch to the Nvidia card when under load. I discussed with a package creator that handled this for Intel/AMD and Intel/Nvidia and he told me he does not support AMD/Nvidia yet...

Comment: I got hybrid graphics working on my ASUS laptop with Ryzen 7 4800H and Nvidia RTX 2070. No smart power saving features, but I've got it setup so that nvidia card is running all the time and using PRIME to render onto the AMD graphics outputs (internal montior, HDMI port). I'm planning to post a full answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244376/cant-get-internal-and-external-monitor-working-simultaneously-with-20-04-on-lap). Short version: I upgraded my kernel to 5.6 and adapted [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only) for amdgpu.