# MSI Bravo 17 and Linux compatibility

Tags: boot, radeon

After receiving my new laptop I bought to code under Ubuntu Linux, I discovered that this product based on AMD Ryzen 4800H (Navi 14 Mobile) VEGA 10 with Radeon RX 5500M is unable to work with Ubuntu!

I am totally disappointed 'cause I bought it to work on Linux but all my tries with the following distributions failed:

- Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, stucks on black screen after installation reboot.
- Linux Mint works with nomodeset but a permanent banner indicating me missing graphic accelerator push me to try AMD Radeon software for Ubuntu 20.04 - since installation - I completely lost any shell command.

Only Windows works, Grrrrrrrrrrrrrr...

Please help if you have any ideas.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here. I haven't read the whole page. https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation

Comment: This answer till the edit part can help you - https://askubuntu.com/a/1251457/310517

Comment: thanks a lot guys, i ll try your suggestion Kumaran til i never found your post. i ll keep you in touch.

Comment: You can also try newer kernels. There is supposed to be better support in newer kernels. I would test 5.6 and 5.7 series of kernels. You find them on `https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/` or download `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`. Make it executable and ask for kernels with e.g. `./ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -r | grep v5.7`. I can make a full recipe if interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!!! It seems working flawlessly ! Before applicate setting to grub file, i removed AMD GPUPRO driver as suggested by another user and i applied update-grub with reboot. Everything seems OK now...

Comment: What about ubuntu 20.04.1, it's coming with 5.6 kernel is it working well with bravo ?

Comment: As my grub settings are still in my defaut configuration, i kept my 2 params : 
    amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1
    amdgpu.runpm=0
i wont try to remove even i switched to new kernel. it s work almosy flawlessly...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should try using nomodeset (as you did).
Second, as Ubuntu (and Mint) are not really up-to-date compared to the new hardware, I suggest trying something in Arch Linux direction. The kernel used by Ubuntu is more than half a year old (with some fixes, but no major changes).
Third, you should NOT use AMD software from their homepage. The best you can do is adding a ppa (like Kisak's Mesa) for newer open source VGA drivers.
Fourth "Yes, AMD doesn't work. Nowhere on linux."
That's totally wrong. They are contributing a lot and the experience is really smooth in the past few years, but only with somewhat older hardware. What they really lack is to be able to have first day support, but after some waiting they won't disappoint you.

Comment: Your answer about the Ubuntu kernel is not totally true. You can upgrade to the latest (not release) kernel versions from the Ubuntu web page. This helped me fix a lot of issues with my system.

Comment: I agree with you. But just looking at the question makes me wonder whether he would be ready for the somewhat harder task (even I don't know which kernel is good right now). Also, with a newer stock kernel update the Grub order would change and his problems would arise again without him knowing what happened. You need to know how things work if you want to apply your own fixes to the system. And most people don't care, they just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my troubles with 2 options in grub.cfg :

- amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1
- amdgpu.runpm=0

With theses options, the laptop is usable for work but the autonomy is quiet bad... only 2h30 ...

All internal software is updated to last version firmware ...

No more AMD for Linux machine !

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved with upgrading to latest kernel and adding following lines in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.runpm=0"
```