# Internal display unclaimed ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, brightness, radeon

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Linux, this is my first time installing Ubuntu.
I've Msi Bravo 15.

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H
GPU: AMD Radeon 5500M

I'm unable to change the brightness of my screen, I booted in replacing quiet splash with nomodeset. I ran **lshw -c video** as written in one of the answers that I read.

> *-display UNCLAIMED

```
    description: Display controller
    product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: c1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff memory:fe500000-fe57ffff memory:fe580000-fe59ffff
```

> *-display UNCLAIMED

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Renoir
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: c7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe400000-fe47ffff
```

The kernel version is 5.8.0 (if relevant)

I've seen a few solutions which I believe might work such as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/h87bn6/msi_bravo_15_ryzen_7_4800h_radeon_rx_5500mbased/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255193/msi-bravo-17-and-linux-compatibility), but even after googling a lot about the commands, I'm unable to make sense of it. The answers are particularly written for users who have a bit of history with Linux I believe. I've already tried updating every driver to latest version.
Based on the comment, here is the output for **lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A2**

> 07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir [1002:1636] (rev c7)
> Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Renoir [1462:12b5]
> Kernel modules: amdgpu

Another thing to note is that, the model I have was probably made for Indian market, it has american style keyboard layout, and 16 gigs of RAM instead of 8 on the German one.

Can someone provide a more detailed solution as what to do?

Comment: It is not quit clear what you have installed. A german user got it running. Please open a terminal and type `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A2`. Copy the output and paste it into your question. It should contain a line such as: **Kernel driver in use: amdgpu**

Comment: @kanehekili, I've added that information.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened but now I'm able to change brightness and it doesn't say display unclaimed anymore. works without nomodeset. I didn't change anything and it just worked. :D

Comment: However, I think I must add it. I had been testing lswh -c video on nomodeset because my screen loaded into darkness., In this mode, I still get display unclaimed, but now that I don't need nomodeset anymore, my problem is solved.

Comment: Yes - nomodeset should only be an emergency flag to get into your system and fix it. Great you've got it solved.