# Not detecting external dispplay with Laptop with AMD CPU + NVIDIA GPU + Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, external-monitor

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2020 HP Omen 15 laptop with AMD CPU and NVidia GPU. Everything works except detecting an external monitor. I have used the "Additional Drivers" software configuration section and unsuccessfully tried all the nvidia drivers listed there (including nvidia-driver-440). The "Displays" setting of the settings app only shows one display, which is titled "Unknown Display". I also noticed that the "Nvidia X Server Settings" App is blank, and also that there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file present.

Comment: This link actually provided a working solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244376/cant-get-internal-and-external-monitor-working-simultaneously-with-20-04-on-lap

Comment: If you think you question is solved it would be great if you could create an answer and elaborate (with the link in your comment) what you did. We think it is great if you ask and find an answer by yourself - so share your experience.

Answer (score -1):

i had the issue with the driver i had installed got corrupted and on installing nvidia-driver-440 and above it started showing dependency error.
now the problem i had solved was with complete fresh installation of a Ubuntu 20.04 and installing nvidia-driver-470
this solved for me but you can check
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470

Comment: Thanks. nvidia driver 470 did not help.